# "The same as him" or "the same as he"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Imagine your friend ordered a pizza ai quattro formaggi.  You want to eat the same thing.  What would you say?

> 1. The same as him.
> 2. The same as he.
> 3. The same as he ordered.
> 4. The same as what he ordered.

Are they all acceptable?  I'm a bit confused with how to use "the same as"

Answer (score 1):

**The same as him** is short for 'Please give me the same as him'. So it's OK.
**The same as he** is short for 'I'll have the same as he has'. So it's OK too, but it sounds old-fashioned and fastidious, like "If only I were as handsome as he!"
**The same as he ordered** and **The same as what he ordered** both sound awkward to me, though "I'd like what he ordered" sounds a bit better.

**But...** pointing at each other, and even referring to each other as 'he/him' or 'she/her', might be considered impolite. "I'd like the same as *my friend*" would be better. And better still would be "I would *also* like the (pizza ai) quattro formaggi (please/per favore)."

Maybe I'm over-sensitive. As a child, if I ever referred to my aunt in her presence as "she", there would be shrieks of "Who's 'she' - the cat's *mother?!*"

Among friends and in an informal setting I'd do as Chspsa in the US suggests and say, "**The same as him**."

Comment: I would say simply "I'll have the same".

Comment: With #1, I'd ask what the prepositional phrase "as him" modifies or refers to. I think that most people would say "the same". But "the same" appears to refer to the pizza. So is the pizza being compared to a person?

Comment: @Kate Bunting: That would only work if the waiter came to you immediately after the friend who ordered the pizza. But if the friend ordered first, followed by his/her spaghetti-eating husband, or by his/her _two carbonara-loving daughters_, "I'll have the same" gets you pasta!

Comment: In a larger party, I'd probably say "I'll have the pizza too".

Comment: Is *pizza ai quattro formaggi* a phrase used in English?

Comment: It's often on the menu in Italian restaurants in the UK.

Comment: @Kate: Oh yes. I forgot "I'll have the pizza too." Perfect.

Comment: How about "the same as his"?

Comment: @kuwabara: No worse than the OP's first two options. But here again 'his' might be deemed just as impolite as 'he/him' etc. I think we've found the most apt options.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers 1, 3, and 4 are correct.

Why is 2 incorrect?

"Him" receives an action. "He" does the action.
The reason 1 is correct is that "Him" is receiving the action of being who I want to copy. 3 and 4 are correct because "he" ordered something. However in a real situation, in AmE, I'd say "The same as him."

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

We can say-

The same as **him**. or

The same as **he ordered**.

We can use *object pronoun* or *subject pronoun + verb*